# Parsed Json data in webView

Tags: ios, iphone, json, xcode, webview

I want to open data from my json database in a webview.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work can someone help me?

```
NSString* jsonString = @"http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php";
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
NSURLRequest* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
[webView loadRequest:linkUrl];
```

Answer (score 1):

get your link in `NSURL` object and then set request with this `NSURL` object like bellow..

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
NSURL *urlforWebView;
urlforWebView=[NSURL URLWithString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"]];
urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlforWebView];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubView:webView]; no visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSubView

Comment: @user1823117 now see the code and use it i edit code.. here you required NSURL to set the url string and the use this url in urlrequest just see the code and add in your code...

Comment: mate u use this line NSURLRequest* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:link]; instead of like this code NSURLRequest* linkUrl urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]]; try this line mate..

Comment: NSString* jsonString = @"http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php";
NSData* jsonData = [jsonStringdataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
//NSURLRequest* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSURLRequest* linkUrl; urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
[webView loadRequest:linkUrl];

Comment: just try this code..  NSString* jsonString = @"http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php";;
    NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL]; 
    NSLog(@"\n\n JSONDATA :==>> %@",jsonDict);
    NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"]; 
    NSURL* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonString]; 
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:linkUrl];

Comment: first download whole data and then when you want to open link just set this link with string in NSURL

Comment: @user1823117 hey mate see this for ur requirement i search now for u.. http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html i hope this help you...

Comment: thank you but i already knew the tut. But it doesn't help me :/

Comment: hey mate but what i told that here u get many record from the url and after that if you parse the data and get field of link like [[ArrayData objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"link"]; now you understand what i tell u??

Comment: download this demo and see the output.. https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON also here i just want to tell that just copy this url http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php and paste on ur browser address bar and see the output.. here you get many data so first parse these all data in dictionory or Array and then use it with "link" key word.. i think read some tutorial for json parsing with url mate

Comment: see the tutorial about it from this link also http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Comment: i can not run the first project

Comment: try from this answers dude.. here give many tutorials and demo for json parsing first follow tutorial please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946898/how-to-do-json-parsing-in-iphone i hope you got it dude...